# What is a difference between FFT in LabView and in Python (SciPy)

Tags: python, scipy, fft, labview, spectrogram

The following is puzzling me: I have a signal (8 bit integer) and two spectrograms computed from it: one in LabView and another in Python.

The shapes of the obtained spectra are identical, however the magnitude is very different. In the example I am dealing with right now, the coefficiient is 1529578.9355375224 which really looks like a random number. Does anyone know what are the differences between the FFT algorithms of LabVIEW and Scipy?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The algorithm should be the same. Your problem sounds like a data conversion problem and not a difference in the algorithm. Could you add your python code so we can spot some issues?

Comment: LabView and Scipy FFT probably do not use the same normalization method. It does not really matter as long as their implementations of the inverse transform is consistent with their forward Fourier transforms.

Comment: Looks pretty much like the square root of `2339611720040`. What's the size of your inputs?

Comment: You mention the comparison of two spectrograms. Considering a signal, you may then compute the power spectrum or the power spectral density, which differs by a scaling factor    And could then explain the difference of magnitude you observe (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) Posting your Python code may help!

Comment: What happens if you use the `numpy/scipy` fft with keyword `norm='ortho'`?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. The spectrogram is calculated like this: spectrogram(data.data, fs=frq, window = win), where spectrogram comes from scipy.signal. The signal length is 62500006.